# Texwork, \usepackage{graphicx} is not working

Tags: graphics, errors, packages

I want to add a image (.pnj) in my latex.
I put:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}

But gives me this error:
! LaTeX Error: File `epstopdf-base.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:

What does it mean? How can I do to add a simple image?

Thank you

Comment: you will have to install the epstopdf-pkg package. How depends on your texsystem.

Comment: note thi sis unrelated to texworks (the editor you are using) but does depend on your tex system, which is most likely miktex or texlive

Comment: Ok, thank you. And what is the command to insert this package?

Comment: That depends on the latex system you are using, of which you have provided no information

Comment: I'm using TEXworks